# How do I add a Corel Draw map as .dxf file to QGIS and how do I georeference it?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have a vector data map of Poland, which I exported from Corel Draw. I can display the map in QGIS. At first the boundaries and subdivisions are only displayed as lines, after saving the data as shapefile, I was able to use the "Line to Polygon"-tool to convert the lines. Now I have a shapefile with multiple features.

Now I want to relocate and distort it to make it fit to my basemap. As you can see in the picture, the Poland shapefile is presented close to Africa because the location is not yet defined correctly.

[image: poland]

There are now several problems:

- I tried to move the Poland shapefile in an edit session but the shapefile contains of multiple polygons and I was not able to move them together. How can I move multiple features at the same time?
- I also tried to make a single polygon by merging the multiple features in an edit session, but when doing it with the "Merge Selected Features"-tool, an error occurs and QGIS crashes.
- Therefore, I tried it with a third way by creating a new shapefile, drawing a polygon, that covers the whole Poland polygons and then cliping both shapefiles. After Cliping, the new shapefile is created and added to the table of contents, but there is nothing displayed on my map.

As you can see, there may be a mistake in the previous steps but I dont know where, I already repeated every step but there is still no solution found. I suspect the problem to be in the step of converting the Corel Draw .dxf file to a shapefile or the transformation from lines to polygons.

Also if you know a more effective way to get my map to its planned location and how to reference it correctly, please let me know your thoughts.

Comment: related: How to georeference a vector layer with control points? http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/33208/how-to-georeference-a-vector-layer-with-control-points?rq=1

Comment: related: QGIS affine - form of equation http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/23998/qgis-affine-form-of-equation?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Here you have shp files with admin division of Poland in WGS84
http://www.filefactory.com/file/6alk9nislrwb/n/POL_adm_zip

This is direct link form http://www.gadm.org/ database

Comment: Thank you for these shapefiles, but these will not help me. The Corel Draw map was drawn manually (with a lot of additional information) and is nearly finished. I need to cut some raster data and then reimport it to Corel Draw. This is why I need the manually created Poland map in GIS to use it as correct template.