# How to shift the Map a little bit?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, coordinate-system, qgis-plugins

I'm having trouble with two maps, both UTM33N/WGS84. They should be exactly on top of each other but there is a slight shift between them of probably a few hundred meters or so.
[image]

I Tried to adjust this with the Vector Affine Transformation Plugin but didn't succeed. I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Have a look at the answer [here](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21696/rotating-a-vector-layer-in-qgis-with-qgsaffine-or-other-method) - qgsAffine is not easy to use, but works once you know the numbers to plug in. I do agree with @Darren Cope's suggestion though - check the origins and intended scale of each layer to see if they even **should** line up.

Comment: Are you sure both datasets are on wgs84? A few hundred meters could be due to different datums.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think we are getting somewhere. The original shapefile (contained in forste-orig.zip) appears to be Pulkovo 1942(83)/Gauss-Kruger Zone 4, which is EPSG:2398. So if you load this into QGIS and set its CRS to EPSG:2398, then save it as EPSG:32633 this should do the trick. Nick.

Answer (score 2):

To me this looks like a 'scale' issue. The layers appear to be drawn at a different level of detail, and thus will never line up exactly. Am I missing something?

Comment: The curves look to have the same level of detail to me.

Comment: @nmpeterson; I really don't think so. Look in the bottom-left corner specifically. There's no way this is can be a 'matching' dataset. Please don't downvote without closer inspection!

Comment: I inspected rather closely. The blobby features' coastal path seem to be a convex hull of the underlying polygons, but shifted dramatically (as the OP believes).

Comment: It doesn't help that the underlying features seem to be only a sample of a larger dataset, making it more difficult for us to know where the actual "coastline" is in certain places, like the lower left -- are those actually islands, or just polygons whose neighbors aren't a part of the sample?

Comment: Which is the dataset with the problems? If it's not confidential could you post a download link? Nick.

Comment: Just another thought, the layer that doesn't fit might be ED50, the shift looks about right. It might be worth trying EPSG:23033 for the layer to see how it reprojects on-the-fly to WGS84/UTM Zone 33.

Comment: Before it was supposedly EPSG: 31468 = PD/83_GK_Zone_4 bzw. DHDN/Gauss-Kruger Zone 4 (QGIS). And I converted the blue layer to uTM33N/WGS84. The purple layer has the correct UTM-Dimensions

Comment: Hi Nick. All right, thank you. It might be the same strange projection as last time...
Upload will be finished 09:25.

www.projektidee.org/images/extern/Forste.zip

Comment: The original projection:

www.projektidee.org/images/extern/forste-orig.zip

Answer (score 2):

Found it! Just go to Layer Styling and adjust the offset, x or y.

[image]