# File SHP needing to be shifted up?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, tableau

I am new in GIS.

I am trying to use the curves of level (downloaded from [this](http://smu.insula.it/index.php@option=com_content&view=article&id=161%253Acurve-di-livello&catid=48%253Alivelli-informativi-in-formato-shape&Itemid=167&lang=it.html) site in SHP format) to use them into Tableau Desktop.

The problem is that if I loaded the lines, they are not correctly setted, as shown in this picture from the same file loaded with QGIS.

How could I fix it?

In the archive I downloaded from the site linked above there are also other 3 files, with extension dbf, prj and shx that maybe can be useful to center the dataset.

[image]

Comment: see this [post](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Difference-EPSG-3004-EPSG-102092-td5087763.html) that explains the issue

Comment: You can check some [relevant answers](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/how-to-shift-the-map-a-little-bit) first. Shifting the shapefile is a common question. Also, I want you to check the projection of your shapefile as well. You need to set the same projection to the background map first.

Comment: set your projection to Monte Mario / Italy zone 2 https://epsg.io/3004

Comment: A single [shapefile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shapefile) is made up of *at least* 3 separate files. In this case, the files (curve_livello_polyline.shp, curve_livello_polyline.dbf, curve_livello_polyline.prj AND curve_livello_polyline.shx) are all *one* shapefile. QGIS is already using all of them to display the layer 'curve_livello_polyline'. This isn't the problem here, but it will cause problems later if you don't know this.