# calibrating vector line in qgis

Tags: qgis, vector, gps, dxf

I have loaded GPS points into a QGIS vector layer. 
I also imported a vector line from a dxf file which doesn't have georeferencing.

I would like to fit in line geometry between the GPS points - how can I do this?

Comment: Please provide at least a screenshot. It's hard to understand the problem otherwise. Also more details on exactly what you are trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an affine transformation, basically, you should use one layer as reference (target) and move the other layer (source). Read [my answer in this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/127653/4972) to get an idea on how to apply it to vector data.

Comment: yeah, I could do this but I wanted to do this in quick way. So I just edit line and move it to GPS position. But thanks anyway. :)