# Copying features to new location using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, editing, fields-attributes

I want to copy some features from one layer and paste them onto another layer with all their attributes, but in a different geographic location. Is this possible? These are very small features a very long way apart, so the cursor-based 'move feature' tool is not really an option.

I'm using QGIS 2.6.

Comment: Do the layers share the Coordinate Reference System (CRS)? If not, you probably want to [apply an affine transformation](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/how-to-compute-parameters-for-qgis-affine-transformation/127653#127653) on one of your layers to move and even scale your layer features before copying them.

Answer (score 1):

When you copy a feature, not only do you copy its visible attributes (ie. from the *Attribute Table*) but you also copy its invisible attributes (ie. [wkt_geom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) which is the coordinates of the features' dimensions). So when you move your features to another geographic location, the coordinates for each dimension will also change. Therefore, I do not think it's possible to copy a feature (which already has a set of coordinates) from one location and paste it to another.

Hopefully others can advise on this!