# SVG to GEOjson with control points

Tags: python, geojson, georeferencing, svg

I have few SVG files (maps) that I want to convert to GEOJson.
On those SVG files, two markers (crosses) had been drown in order to georeference the layer. 
So I know the coordinates of those control points, I am able to calculate the parameters : [How to compute parameters for QGIS Affine transformation?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/30559/how-to-compute-parameters-for-qgis-affine-transformation/127653#127653).

My plan is :

- Read the SVG file and extract the paths.
- Store the coordinates of the shapes in an array
- Apply the affine transformation
- Write a GEOJson file

I have already extracted the paths with python (svgpathtool), but I have no clue on how to exploit that.

Is there a better way to do that ?

How to translate the path ?

Comment: Dear Antonie, do you have made some progress on this? I'm facing a similar problem. How did you solve it?