# How to rotate North oriented Map

Tags: qgis, shapefile, mapinfo

I want to rotate my North oriented point shapefile to 45%, is there any way to rotate it QGIS or MapInfo?

Comment: Do you wish to print a rotated Map, or do you wish to rotate the actual data itself?

Comment: i want to rotate the actual data itself.

Comment: Hm, well the question yo claim this is a duplicate of, only asks about QGIS. This question asks about QGIS or MapInfo, so I guess it's not a complete duplicate

Answer (score 1):

In QGis you need to use the Affine Plugin (plugins->Fetch Python Plugin) or you could do it using PostGIS.

Have a look at [this thread](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/21696/rotating-a-vector-layer-in-qgis-with-qgsaffine-or-other-method) for further description on correct usage.

Comment: This doesn't rotate the data, only the Map in the print.

Comment: Editted answer to reflect that the OP wants to rotate the data and not the map.

Answer (score 0):

In MapInfo Professional you can rotate selected objects by any angel around a specific coordinate.

1. Make the alyer editable
2. Select the objects you want to rotate
3. Select Objects > Rotate and enter the angle and a coordinate you want to rotate the data around
4. Hit OK

If you data currently is stored in a shape file, you need to save it into a tab file to be able to edit it.